# How to make LI innerText have indentation

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Edit:** This HTML is output from a Flash application & its badly formed because it contains li elements NOT inside a ul or ol element. Is there a way to get the desired indentation with this HTML(using CSS)? Hopefully I wont have to parse the HTML & insert my ol tags where I need to, hopefully :(

```
<textformat leading="2">
<li>
    <font style=" font-family: 'arial'; font-size: 14px; color: #FFFFFF; letter-spacing: 0px; ">
    Remaining optimistic and focused while paying attention to the doubts of others
    </font>
</li>
</textformat>
```

**Is there a way to make EVERY line of text inside a HTML *li* element be indented?**

Example of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

This is what currently happens which is what I am trying to avoid:
[image]

So I have this html:

```
<ol>
   <li><font>text here <b>some bold</b></font></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This should happen by default: http://jsfiddle.net/Rqwwe/. Can you post some code/a demo page?

Comment: @Ray Toal: edited my post, it seems the HTML is badly formed, its output from a Flash Application

Comment: That Flash application ouputs `<font>` tags?  Yikes! Run! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `padding` and `text-indent`:

```
li {
    text-indent: -1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

**[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/PFWcK/) on JSFiddle.**

Answer (score 0):

<s>It displays like that fine in all majors browsers by default. The only way you'll get the wrap around like the second example is if you actually wrote the numbers themselves instead of using:</s>

```
<ol>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
</ol>
```

There shouldn't be a problem as long as you use these tags. The only way you should be getting the second image is with the CSS style `list-style-position: inside;`. Should you have some strange stylesheet interfering with your example, you could add `style="list-style-position: outside;"` to the `<ol>` tag to ensure that the numbers are outside of the text.

---

Oh, gah... post edit:

`<li>` isn't really gonna work, then. Why not use a div for each one like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aMdm9/